# How to draw images like in dropbox

Tags: image, drawing, dropbox, photoshop, sketching

I have some images but I need them to be like dropbox images. How can I do this? Is there any software available?

I want my images to be like this,

https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/index/1-vflbLvAPq.png

https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/index/2-vflawKxYX.png

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

You need to use photo shop. Just design your line art or whatever on a transparent background, then when you export. Export as png with transparency. You might want to select a matte color that is the same as the background of the page you plan to put it on. Let me know if this is what you mean...